# Run CMD Silently

Tags: vb.net, cmd, silent

I'm trying to run CMD silently, but each time I get an error. Could someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
Dim myProcess As Process 
myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden 
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True 
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = ("cmd.exe" & CmdStr) 
myProcess.Start()
```

CmdStr is already a string  to do certain things that I want in the application.

Comment: Well on the code it says that I a null exception might occur. But I am changing someone elses code and they have an error trap that just has a message box

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose your cmdStr is a string with parameters for CMD.
If so you need to use the Arguments property of StartInfo.
You get a Null Exception on the myProcess variable because it is never instatiated with new.
You could create a ProcessStartInfo var to use with the static Process.Start method and set the UseShellExecute to False

```
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("CMD.EXE")
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden     
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = True 
startInfo.UseShellExecute = False
startInfo.Arguments = CmdStr
Process.Start(startInfo)
```

or edit your code to add

```
myProcess = new Process()
```

before using the var myProcess

Comment: Thanks Steve, The parts I was missing were the New (hadn't set the instance of the object and the time and the argument section), your unedited version worked after I added in new. Thanks Very Much