# command window not closed after restart PC Remotly using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to run two cmd commands in vb.net

```
Dim command As String ="Net USE \\serverip\IPC$ password /USER:username"

 Dim command2 As String ="shutdown /r /t 3 /m \\serverip"

Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k" + command)

Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C" + command2)
```

Command window is opened how can we close this.

I try `process.kill()` it is not working.

Comment: Did you try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477776/run-cmd-silently

Comment: Thanks @wingedpanther .It's working fine for me

Comment: Even though you make the CMD window invisible, chances are that it is still opened. Add `exit` to the end of **both** commads: **1)** `Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k " & command & " & exit")` **2)** `Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C " & command2 & " & exit")`.

Comment: Please also read [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734600/the-difference-between-and-for-joining-strings-in-vb-net)

Comment: i cannot put exit at the end of first command because i need need opened after second command  first command shuld be closed