# Running CMD commands in VB with parameters

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, cmd

I'm creating an application in Visual Studio. When the user clicks a button, I want the follow CMD command to be executed:

```
xcopy /s/y "C:\myfile.txt" "D:\"
```

I've tried this with Process.Start() but it won't work. The button code is:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Process.Start("CMD", "/C xcopy /s/y "C:\myfile.txt" "D:\"")
End Sub
```

Does anyone know how I can make this work? I suspect that the problem is caused by the /s/y parameters or quotes in the CMD command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code won't compile: you need to escape the double-quotes in the string. In VB.NET you escape quotes using double-double quotes:

```
Process.Start( "CMD", "/C xcopy /s/y ""C:\myfile.txt"" ""D:\""" )
```

Comment: This works fine, thanks! However, the command prompt window stays open after clicking the button. Do you know how I can close that automatically after executing the xcopy, something like the exit command or even better, don't show the CMD screen at all to the user?

Comment: @elton73: `xcopy /?`

Comment: @elton73 : See [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12477832/3740093), and also append `& exit` before the last quote.

Comment: @Visual Vincent: as a newbie to VB I'm not sure how to apply this answer to my code. This won't work: Process.Start( "CMD", "/C xcopy /s/y ""C:\myfile.txt"" ""D:\"" & exit" ).

Comment: @elton73 : That should at least close it. The answer I linked to you can just copy-paste and write your arguments in place of `CmdStr`: `startInfo.Arguments = "/C xcopy /s/y ""C:\myfile.txt"" ""D:\"" & exit"`.

Comment: @Visual Vincent: Yes! Now I got it working by applying this solution. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @elton73 : Glad I could help! Good luck!